# Image processing with python for braille language

Tags: python

how can I extract white paper(that contains Dots 'braille language') from image  in image processing ?
I tried a lot of things but I want to extract it completely so I can do threshold on the result.

Comment: Showing a **representative** example image would be a good start, along with what you expect to extract and your best attempt at coding it so far.

Answer (score 0):

One way you might implement braille detection is using a Hough transform from OpenCV's library.

There is a function [cv.HoughCircles()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) that allows you to specify a radius for circles you are looking for, assuming each sheet of braille paper will be the same distance from your camera you have a known tolerance for that.

I would just be worried about the clarity of white braille bumps on white background paper, which perhaps could be fixed using a perpendicular light source to create some shadows for each bump.